# T-SQL Projected using Lead

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    PeriodBegin, PeriodEnd,
    Amt, Released
    (LEAD(Released, 4, 0) OVER (ORDER BY PeriodEnd DESC) * .29) ProjectedCashCollection
FROM 
    table
```

These are my results:

[image]

I'm trying to have the `ProjectedCashCollection` column populated for all the `PeriodEnd` dates.

Is there a code to project out for the addtional 4 weeks?

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: You mean some form of interpolation? Without proper example data with expected output it's a tough job to answer your question....

Comment: For 5/19/18, I would expect to see the released amount from 4/21/18 1983663.38 * .29 and so forth. I hope that helps explain the results I’m expected to see.